# Change color of text when hovering over parent div CSS

Tags: html, css, hover

I have div that has a hover effect attached to it. This div contains 2 other divs with text, with styled text color.

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="top">
         test
    </div>
    <div class="bottom red">
        test red
    </div>
</div>
```

and css:

```
 .item {
    width: 480px;
    height: 970px;
    background: #cccccc;
    font-size: 60px;
    color:#0073b5;
    text-align: center;
}

.red {
    color:#ff2400;
}

.item:hover {
    background: blue;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.top {
    height: 466px;
}

.bottom {
    padding-top: 85px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

When I hover over any part of the `item` div, I need all the texts in nested divs to change the color to white.

Currently only text in `top` changes its color, however text in `bottom red` doesn't.

I've tried different combinations but the best I've got is to change `bottom red` color to white only when mouse over that div and not when mouseover over other parts of `item`.

Please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**.red** will explicitly override the color. Make your selector stronger, eg:

```
.item:hover > * {
    color: #ffffff;
}
// Other examples
.item:hover > div
.item:hover *
// Or explicitly declare .red too
.item:hover,
.item:hover .red
// As worst solution, you have !important
.item:hover {
    background: blue;
    color: #ffffff !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In CSS the most specific rule wins. Try adding the following rule to your CSS.

```
.item:hover .red {
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, but will have to accept the other more detailed answer.